# How to prove that if $x^2+c\sqrt{b+x^2}=y^2+c\sqrt{b+y^2}$ then $x=y$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, graphing-functions, nonlinear-system

I have a function of $x^2$ as $f(x^2)=x^2+c\sqrt{b+x^2}$ and $f(y^2)=y^2+c\sqrt{b+y^2}$ now suppose $f(x^2)=f(y^2)$, How can I prove that $x=y$ if there is a constraint that both $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. Taking squares do not help as they further add more terms with square roots.

Can I show that show using graph? But the graphs will overlap.

Comment: actually it might be better to say x = `±` y

Comment: is there any constraint on $b$ and $c?$

Comment: You can try by replacing $x^2$ and $y^2$ with $p^2-b$ and $q^2-b$ respectively. Then, you can show $p=q$, which finally leads to the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& f\left(x^2\right)=x^2+c \sqrt{b+x^2} \\
& f\left(y^2\right)=y^2+c \sqrt{b+y^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

x &y are positive integers
$$
\text { if } f\left(x^2\right)=f\left(y^2\right) \text { prove that } x=y
$$
Let's assume, x not equal to y.

Let $\text{ Case 1: if x<y}\Rightarrow y=x+h, \Rightarrow h \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\therefore f\left(y^2\right) & =(x+h)^2+c \sqrt{b+x^2+h^2+2 x h} \\
& =x^2+h^2+2 x h+c \sqrt{b+x^2+h^2+2 x h} \\
& =f\left(x^2\right)=x^2+c \sqrt{b+x^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
$\Rightarrow h^2+2 x h=c\left\{\sqrt{b+x^2}-\sqrt{b+x^2+h^2+2 x h}\right\}$

Since,  x is a positive integer, we can clearly see that no such $h$ exists.

Case 2: if $x>y \Rightarrow x=y+h, \Rightarrow h \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
f\left(x^2\right) & =f\left(y^2\right) \\
\Rightarrow(y+h)^2+c \sqrt{b+(y+h)^2} & \\
& =y^2+c \sqrt{b+y^2} \\
\Rightarrow h^2+2 y h & =c\left\{\sqrt{b+y^2}-\sqrt{b+(y+h)^2}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Again its clear no such $h$ exists. Why? Since y is a positive integer.

$\therefore$ our assumption falls,
Hence $x=y$, Q.E.D.

Comment: Do you assume that $b,c>0?$

Comment: Although I hv went through it multiple times. Slight typing errors might be there. Although I am sure the community admins will take care of it and help me with that concern.

Comment: If $c<0,$ your proof is incomplete (so, invalid). I asked a question concerning $b,c$ but @Anjanyea does not answer.

Comment: @user37643 I am so sorry. That thing just skipped my attention. Thanks a lot for bringing into notice.

Answer (score 1):

If $\;b\ge0,c>0,$ the function
$$f(t)=t+c\sqrt{b+t}$$ is the sum of two increasing functions on $[0,\infty),$ so it is increasing on $[0,\infty).$ Therefore, $f$ is injective and
$$f(x^2)=f(y^2) \quad \iff \quad x^2=y^2.$$
The claim is true for any positive reals $x,y,$ not only for integers.

---

If $\;b\ge0, c<0,$ the function is defined on $[0,\infty),$ but is not monotone. The claim is false, as shows the following counterexample:

Let $b=5, c=-3-\sqrt6.$

Then $$f(1^2)=1-(3+\sqrt6)\sqrt{6}=-5-3\sqrt6$$
and also
$$f(2^2)=4-(3+\sqrt6)\sqrt{9}=-5-3\sqrt6$$
For the integers $x=1, y=2$ are the values equal, but $x\neq y.$

Comment: Thanks for providing a more fuller answer.